Is my proof that the set of non-injective linear transformations is not a subspace of $\mathcal{} (  ,  )$ correct?
I just want to know if my proof for the question below is valid.
30. Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional with $2 \leq \dim V \leq \dim W$. Show that the set $A = \{ T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W) \mid T \text{ is not injective} \}$ is not a subspace of $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$.
Proof: To demonstrate that $A$ is not a subspace, we need to show that at least one of the following conditions fails:

$A$ contains the zero vector,
$A$ is closed under addition,
$A$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

First, the zero transformation $Z$ defined by $Zv = 0$ for all $v \in V$ is not injective, so $Z \in A$.
Next, consider two distinct transformations $S, R \in A$ such that $\text{null } S \cap \text{null } R = \{0\}$ and $S \neq -R$. We analyze their sum:
$$
(S + R)v = Sv + Rv = 0.
$$
This equality holds only if $Sv = 0$ and $Rv = 0$. Given $\text{null } S \cap \text{null } R = \{0\}$, it follows that $v = 0$ is the only solution. Thus, $\text{null }(S + R) = \{0\}$, indicating that $S + R$ is injective. Consequently, $A$ is not closed under addition.
Since $A$ fails the closure property under addition, it cannot be a subspace of $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$.$\square$

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

@JoséCarlosSantos was there anything that wasn't clear about my question?

No. Has that something to do with my comment?

@JoséCarlosSantos "A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title." I thought this was in reference to my question.

The question itself is only in the title. You should edit your post and add the question to it.

How do you know that $S$ and $R$ exist? Even if they exist, the rest of the argument is not correct.

@JoséCarlosSantos Noted. Thanks.

@geetha290krm could you please elaborate?

Did you use the hypothesis that $\dim V\geqslant2$?

@JoséCarlosSantos No. I didn't.

Then your proof cannot be correct, since the space $A$ is a subspace of $\mathcal L(V,W)$ when $1=\dim V\leqslant\dim W$. In this case, $A={0}$.

@JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for pointing that out. Would my proof be correct if I assume $\dim V \geq 2$?

Of course not! You will have to use that hypothesis somewhere. Just stating that you are assuming it is not enough.

Hello,
I will try to give you small hint on this. You also have to use the fact that V and W are finite dimensional. One more thing when you claim $R, S$ you specifically have to construct them (constructing a linear transform is defining on it's basis) and then show that $R+S$ is not injective. While constructing such $R, S$ you may need the hypothesis $\dim V \geq 2$.

You wrote  "consider two distinct transformations $S,R\in A$ such that $\mathrm{null } S \cap \mathrm{null } R={0}$ and $S\ne −R$". How convenient that those transformations exists! Wait, why those exists?

@redshellspy Interesting. I might need to think more about it. Thank you.

Your proof is incomplete, since you did not say how is it that you know that $S$ and $R$ exist.
Let $v_1$ and $v_2$ be two linearly independent vectors of $V$; they must exist since $\dim V\geqslant2$. Now, extend the set $\{v_1,v_2\}$ to a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,V_n\}$ of $V$, where $n=\dim V$. Fix a set $\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}\in W\setminus\{0\}$ of linearly independent vectors of $W$; it must exist, since $\dim W\geqslant\dim V$. Let $S_1\colon V\longrightarrow W$ be the linear map such that $S_1(v_1)=w_1$ and that $S_1(v_k)=0$ if $k>1$. Also, let $S_2\colon V\longrightarrow W$ be the linear map such that $S_2(v_1)=0$ and that $S_2(v_k)=w_k$ if $k>1$. Then $S_1,S_2\in A$, but $S_1+S_2\notin A$, since $(S_1+S_2)(v_k)=w_k$ for each $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

I'm glad I could help.
